# В логах обрезает параметры

Tags: php, yii

Как называется в php.ini константа, которая позволяет увеличить ограничение на размер лога, чтобы он не обрезал параметры?
Пример обрезанных параметров в логах:

```
#2 /home/localhost/public_html/framework/web/CBaseController.php(95): CBaseController->renderInternal('/home/localhost/...', Array, true)
```

Comment: можно получить пример кода, в котором записывается лог?

Comment: лог пишет логгер yii1
        'log' => array(
            'class' => 'CLogRouter',
            'routes' => array(
                array(
                    'class' => 'CDbLogRoute',
                    'levels' => 'error, warning',
                    'connectionID' => 'db'
                ),
            ),
        ),